# Verification of RSA key signatures always returns false

Tags: java, rsa, digital-signature, sign, verify

I have created the following method to check if the RSA keys are able to sign and verify the signature:

```
public static boolean checkKeys(RSAPrivateKey privateKey, RSAPublicKey publicKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    byte[] data = { 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74 };

    Signature signer = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA", "BC");
    signer.initSign(privateKey);
    signer.update(data);

    byte[] signature = signer.sign();

    Signature verifier = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA", "BC");
    verifier.initVerify(publicKey);
    verifier.update(data);

    return verifier.verify(signature); 
}
```

But it always returns `false`. Even if I use RSA key pair that is definitely correct.

What I am missing?

**EDIT:**

Here is the whole part source code for verification of RSA signature, together with test RSA key:

```
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        String modulus = "6196090b423ba91c28bf6cf10de26bf530d9178c10e51a01ab4476abf2f9f1428eca5db7af5d3f9626bce5b16548a8550eba113bb141494b2f682b8971a537ded23e4071fcdc1156f917cb6dfe2cd084736623b8c6110b724298876d5a21e36a775b90d0ec077bef39e57d551d11a6299f5e45ad6d1ec88bd290118f2d605357";
        String publicExponent = "010001";
        String privateExponent = "5037134214f493a2d8ffd95e208aa1315030f34128561a558ae1e126a0b8c18f736e7730d94eae490f98b0ba6c461850aaa55a2b161e5350212ce0b4bf1d0f59ecc0cff6723dc65aa776a35177e025d3b50f5b49cedd4b897bdb2f97f0415f7655f2e731972fc9b9a5c868dfdd8fe3806315f76e661690f9c3a5aacf170b0711";
        String primeP = "8b1648f46e7b199f2da610869f1148d26689e3095d7d5de00af92287860791f842d943a15b0c5f3cc24e804c47e838b27f8e7749373974a238c37d87bb65c6df";
        String primeQ = "b39d4874941830f6e12dcf39263c7f2a8b7ac5766f57e64768700d3897796027bce4969f4f5b823ba85c39c50abf626442aaaa8900e690225b5857023451da89";
        String primeExponentP = "97f7e00e922e677cca628d2495dc0660cfd29fc56547f29b935b95153df047fbcdb1f21b4fe9d15932ac81d9b1936a748b8fea7798ff39100bfc56a473d19a45";
        String primeExponentQ = "95234475ec93c190af25c4f3328a88470b369153addec12207f495049d0d8ace0596f4ecb73e9b77acc03e2a8cd61c1f976c682c5690d5dd914d6436b2afd48d";
        String crtCoefficient = "12baadb22b28d1352b2ac335617c4cd0fe3416c6b3054020950a20700c8dba7ae41946dcec842f29c149032488bc3fadead4eeae0e66935e245b407e99c49b9a";

        BigInteger modulusBI = new BigInteger(1, Utils.hexStringToByteArray(modulus));
        BigInteger publicExponentBI = new BigInteger(1, Utils.hexStringToByteArray(publicExponent));
        BigInteger privateExponentBI = new BigInteger(1, Utils.hexStringToByteArray(privateExponent));
        BigInteger primePBI = new BigInteger(1, Utils.hexStringToByteArray(primeP));
        BigInteger primeQBI = new BigInteger(1, Utils.hexStringToByteArray(primeQ));
        BigInteger primeExponentPBI = new BigInteger(1, Utils.hexStringToByteArray(primeExponentP));
        BigInteger primeExponentQBI = new BigInteger(1, Utils.hexStringToByteArray(primeExponentQ));
        BigInteger crtCoefficientBI = new BigInteger(1, Utils.hexStringToByteArray(crtCoefficient));

        KeyFactory rsaFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "BC");

        RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec privateCrtKeySpec = new RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec(
                modulusBI,
                publicExponentBI,
                privateExponentBI,
                primePBI,
                primeQBI,
                primeExponentPBI,
                primeExponentQBI,
                crtCoefficientBI
                );
        RSAPrivateCrtKey privateKeyCRTDev = (RSAPrivateCrtKey) rsaFactory.generatePrivate(privateCrtKeySpec);

        RSAPublicKeySpec publicKeySpec = new java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec(privateKeyCRTDev.getModulus(), privateKeyCRTDev.getPublicExponent()); 
        RSAPublicKey publicKeyDev = (RSAPublicKey) rsaFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

        byte[] data = { 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74 };

        Signature signer = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA", "BC");
        signer.initSign(privateKeyCRTDev);
        signer.update(data);

        byte[] signature = signer.sign();

        Signature verifier = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA", "BC");
        verifier.initVerify(publicKeyDev);
        verifier.update(data);

        boolean ok = verifier.verify(signature);
```

This return always `false`. What is wrong with my testing key if the private and public key does not match? Why the signature can't be verified?

Comment: You are missing nothing. The keypair does not match.

Comment: The private key is RSAPrivateCRTKey with the same modulus and public exponent as RSAPublicKey. The RSAPublicKey wa created from modulus and public exponent of RSAPrivateCRTKey. So how there could not be a match between the private and public key?